# Weird Cell Value in BIRT Excel Format

Tags: java, excel, reporting, birt

BIRT 4.4 has been stable when it comes to PDF exported format.

When I opted for Excel format, I don't know why, the last row which contains the summation of three columns shows "Fixed" instead of the actual value.

Actually, the Excel formula bar contains the actual correct value.

[image]

What's the nature of this bug? and how can I solve it?

Comment: This question can be improved by providing the version of BIRT you are using as well as the emitter if you not using the OOB choice for the version.

Comment: I use BIRT 4.4, and I instanciate **EXCELRenderOption()** class. I am not sure about the emitter though?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't run across your exact bug, but one that was very similar.

I had to manually edit the XML number format to fix cells that said "Percent" instead of being formatted as a percent.

I'm guessing you currently see "Fixed" in the pattern element, but will need to change it as follows:

```
<property name="category">Fixed</property>
<property name="pattern">###0.00{RoundingMode=HALF_UP}</property>
```

Reference:
https://bitbucket.org/yaytay/spudsoft-birt-excel-emitters/issues/105/data-elements-with-percent-number